# How do I check if an specific element inside my SQL array is followed by another one?

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

So, I have a grouped table that pretty much looks like this:

| ID | event | date1 | date2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | click | 2021-01-05 | 2021-01-06 |
|  | impression | 2021-01-05 | 2021-01-06 |
|  | click | 2021-04-03 | 2021-04-04 |
|  | click | 2021-05-07 | 2021-05-08 |
| 090 | impression | 2021-02-02 | 2021-02-03 |
|  | impression | 2021-06-04 | 2021-06-05 |
| 033 | click | 2021-03-15 | 2021-04-16 |
|  | impression | 2021-03-15 | 2021-04-16 |
| 064 | impression | 2021-05-17 | 2021-05-18 |
|  | click | 2021-06-19 | 2021-06-20 |

I need to get only the ids of users who first clicked and ad (value click on the event column) and saw and ad (impression value on the event column) at the same day in this exact order. The date1 is where we have to look to know if the events happened on the same day. The final result is something like this:

| ID | event | date1 | date2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | click | 2021-01-05 | 2021-01-06 |
|  | impression | 2021-01-05 | 2021-01-06 |
| 033 | click | 2021-03-15 | 2021-04-16 |
|  | impression | 2021-03-15 | 2021-04-16 |

I tried several methods but none of them worked. This what I'm asking can be done using only sql?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below solution

```
select id, array_agg(event_rec) data
from `project.dataset.table`, unnest(data) event_rec
where event_rec.event in ('click', 'impression')
group by id, date1
having count(distinct event) = 2
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Hello Mikhail! For some reason, the query doesn't work and I get the following error: Unrecognized name: events at [6:10]. I'm pretty sure the it is not working because of the aliasing (aliasing never worked for me in BQ). Is there any other way around?

Comment: please clarify schema of your table. is `event`, `date1` and `date2` separate repeated column or they struct of same repeated column (the later was my assumption for my answer)

Comment: This is the schema: https://imgur.com/a/PUwsJak (it is not in english, but i'm sure you'll get it).

Comment: oh, Ok. so just replace `events` with `data`! I just did it in my answer. Try and let me know if still issue :o)

Comment: It worked, but only when I remove the 'having count(distinct event) = 2'. If I don't remove the having, i get the 'this query returned no results'

Comment: @MarcosDias . . . This doesn't guarantee that "impression" immediately follows "click", which seems to be fundamental to your question.

Comment: I think following is the core of logic - `The date1 is where we have to look to know if the events happened on the same day` and within the day  - using date types  - no way to identify order as they below to just same day  :o)

Answer (score 0):

You can unnest and reaggregate . . . I am thinking:

```
select t.*,
       (select [event, next_event]
        from (select event,
                     lead(event) over (partition by date1 order by n) as next_event,
                     n
              from unnest(t.events) event with offset n
             ) e
        where next_event.event = 'impression' and
              event.event = 'click'
        qualify row_number() over (order by n) = 1
       ) as events
from t;
```

EDIT:

If you are looking specifically for the first two elements of the array, then this is simply:

```
select t.*,
       [event[safe_ordinal(1)].event, event[safe_ordinal(2)].event]
from t
where event[safe_ordinal(1)].event = 'click' and
      event[safe_ordinal(2)].event = 'impression';
```

Comment: When I run your query, I got an error here: from unnest(t.events) event with offset n

To get the grouped events, I used:

ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(events, date1, date2, ORDER BY date1 ASC) AS data

So my columns are data.events, data.date1 and data.date2. Sorry for not mentioning that.
That way I don't know how to use it, because neither 'data.events' nor just 'events' works.